# Pip installs console_scripts entry point even when required extra is not present

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

Given this fairly minimal setup.py (greenlet and gevent are just placeholders for arbitrary dependencies)

```py
from setuptools import find_namespace_packages, setup

setup(
    name='foo',
    version='0.0.1',
    platforms='any',
    packages=find_namespace_packages(),
    install_requires=['greenlet'],
    extras_require={
        'bar': ['gevent']
    },
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'foo-script = foo.script:main',
            'bar-script = foo.bar:main [bar]'
        ]
    }
)
```

with `foo/script.py` containing this

```py
def main():
    try:
        import greenlet
    except:
        print('Dependency missing.')
    else:
        print('Found dependency.')
```

and `foo/bar.py` containing this

```py
def main():
    try:
        import gevent
    except:
        print('Dependency missing.')
    else:
        print('Found dependency.')
```

I would assume that, when I run `pip install .`, it would just install `foo-script` and only install `bar-script` if I did `pip install .[bar]`.

However, I find that `bar-script` is installed in any case, expectedly telling me "Dependency missing" in the first case.
According to the [documentation on entry points](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html#dependency-management), I would have assumed that this would not be the case, so I am wondering if this is the intended behavior.
If it is, I am not sure I understand the point of being able to specify dependencies for individual entry points in the first place, if not even core ecosystem tooling like `pip` seems to honor them.